# Specify optimist / minimist command line options which are equally available to Node app whether executed via Node, Nodemon or Istanbul/Mocha

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, mocha.js, nodemon

So I have a number of methods by which I run my node app:

Production, and running for WebDriver tests:

```
node app.js
```

Development

```
nodemon app.js
```

Mocha tests

```
istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec
```

I'd like to use Optimist / Minimist module to handle command line options however, is there any way to provide those arguments to all of the above commands in a way that is consistently handled by my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more digging I finally got the answers.

Nodemon will pass on all arguments as is:

```
nodemon app.js --env=dev
```

Mocha will do the same, however you must specify a filename after spec or else it tries to interpret the command line args itself. So even though mocha defaults to `test/test.js`, specifying this allows command line args to pass to the app:

```
istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec test/test.js --env=test
```